# In PHP, what does this block of code do in forms required field?

Tags: php, html, forms

**What does this block of PHP code do?**

```
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

**This is the entire PHP Program**

*It is taken from w3schools.com
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_required*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $website;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Above your block :  `trim()` function is used to remove the white spaces and other predefined characters from the left and right sides of a string.`stripslashes()` function removes backslashes.`htmlspecialchars()` function converts some predefined e.g for  characters to HTML entities.& (ampersand) becomes &amp;

Comment: It is helpful if user insert malicious data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What it does*

`trim()` removes whitespace from the beginning and end, `stripslashes()` any slash that might be added if magic_quotes is active (which depends on your PHP configuration&version), and `htmlspecialchars()` adds slashes again.

*Why*

The theme here is **XSS Prevention**. However, there is more to learn about this than simply applying `htmlspecialchars()` before outputting it with `echo`. You can [search for this topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xss%20prevention%20html%20php).

Also, a fun way to learn about this is [this website](https://google-gruyere.appspot.com/) that presents challenges where you try to play the hacker's part.

Answer (score 0):

using this sample :

```
    <?php if(isset($_POST['cf_submit'])) {    
   $errors = array();
   $success = null;

   $required_fields['cf_name'] = 'You are required to enter your Name.';
   $required_fields['cf_email'] = 'You are required to enter your E-mail Address.';
   $required_fields['cf_subject'] = 'You are required to enter a Subject.';
   $required_fields['cf_message'] = 'You are required to enter a Message.';

   foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      if(array_key_exists($key, $required_fields)) {
         if(trim($_POST[$key]) === '') {
             $errors[$key] = $required_fields[$key];
          }
       }
    }
    if(empty($errors)) {
         $to = "__email__";
         $subject = $_POST['cf_subject'];
         $name_field = $_POST['cf_name'];
         $email_field = $_POST['cf_email'];
         $message = $_POST['cf_message'];
         $company = $_POST['cf_company'];

         $body = "From: $name_field\n Company: $company\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";
         $success = mail($to, $subject, $body);
    }

    if($success) {
              echo "<p><strong>Thank you for getting in touch. Expect to hear back from us soon.</strong></p>";
         } else {
              echo "<strong>Error sending email! </strong>";
         }
    }
    if(!empty($errors)) {
         echo "<strong>Please check the following errors:</strong><br/><br/>";
         echo "<ul>";
         foreach($errors as $value) {         
              echo "<li>$value</li>";      
         }
         echo "</ul>";
    } ?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="cf_name" type="text" id="cf_name" class="cf_input" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cf_name'])) echo $_POST['cf_name'];?>" placeholder="Name*">
    <input name="cf_email" type="email" id="cf_email" class="cf_input" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cf_email'])) echo $_POST['cf_email'];?>" placeholder="Email*">
    <input name="cf_subject" type="text" id="cf_subject"  class="cf_input" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cf_subject'])) echo $_POST['cf_subject'];?>" placeholder="Subject*">
    <textarea name="cf_message" cols="45" rows="6" id="cf_message" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cf_message'])) echo $_POST['cf_message'];?>" placeholder="Message*" class="cf_text"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="cf_submit">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is basically sanitizing the form input.

This is the break up of your program :

**This strips the leading and trailing whitespaces from $data variable**

```
$data = trim($data);
```

Example :

```
$data = "  abc ";
$data = trim($data); // $data = "abc"
```

**This removes backslashes in $data**

```
$data = stripslashes($data);
```

Example :

```
$data = "I\'m mrid";
$data = stripslashes($data); // $data = "I'm mrid"
```

**This escapes `<html>` tags in $data. This is used to prevent the browser from executing the tags when this data gets sent to them**

```
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
```

Example :

```
$data = "Hello <b>mrid</b>";
$data = htmlspecialchars($data); // $data = "Hello <b>mrid</b>" but this can be displayed as it is on a webpage and won't print mrid in bold.
```